# How to use Google Material Design Sprite icons..?

Tags: css, sprite, sprite-sheet, google-material-icons

I am trying to use Google Material Icons Sprite.. 
the CSS they are providing is something like this

```
.icon {
  background-image: url(../images/sprite-alert-white.PNG);
}
.icon-ic_add_alert_white_24dp {
  background-position: -0px -0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_error_outline_white_24dp {
  background-position: -32px -0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_error_white_24dp {
  background-position: -0px -32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_warning_white_24dp {
  background-position: -32px -32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon {
  background-image: url(../images/sprite-alert-black.PNG);
}
.icon-ic_add_alert_black_24dp {
  background-position: -0px -0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_error_black_24dp {
  background-position: -32px -0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_error_outline_black_24dp {
  background-position: -0px -32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_warning_black_24dp {
  background-position: -32px -32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon {
  background-image: url(../images/sprite-toggle-white.PNG);
}
.icon-ic_check_box_outline_blank_white_24dp {
  background-position: -0px -0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_check_box_white_24dp {
  background-position: -32px -0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_indeterminate_check_box_white_24dp {
  background-position: -0px -32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_radio_button_checked_white_24dp {
  background-position: -32px -32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_radio_button_unchecked_white_24dp {
  background-position: -64px -0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_star_border_white_24dp {
  background-position: -64px -32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_star_half_white_24dp {
  background-position: -0px -64px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-ic_star_white_24dp {
  background-position: -32px -64px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon {
  background-image: url(../images/sprite-toggle-black.PNG);
}
```

The confusion is 
when i am trying to use

```
<div class="icon icon-ic_add_alert_white_24dp"></div>
```

It works Awesome... 
but when i put this...

```
 <div class="icon icon-ic_add_alert_black_24dp"></div>
```

it doesn't work ... i think because the .icon is set multiple times and it takes either first or last value of **.icon** depending upon the browser..

> .icon {   background-image: ---------

but its Google they must have validated their CSS, Can you guide how it should work , i am new to Sprites...

REF

1) https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/sprites

2) https://design.google.com/icons/

Please Help

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your post.

Comment: the issue is very simple, google's CSS is using 
 .icon { background-image: url ();
more than two times in a single file with different URLS
...so i am not able to get all the icons . :(

Comment: For questions asking "why isn't my code working" you *must* provide a complete working reproduction of the problem in your question. AKA we need at least enough of your HTML and your CSS to reproduce this problem ourselves.

Comment: For your second reference they use a font none sprite imgs

Comment: why don't use this: https://design.google.com/icons ?

Comment: `Don't forget to publish the corresponding CSS and SVG/PNG files when deploying your project.` From github ... you need just the css and img for black icons or the png and css for white icons

Comment: @DaniP I did it from Bower as suggested by Google 
but still its not working as its only picking up the first Image and not the second one..

Comment: @GermanoPlebani i cant use Font icons because i am developing a corporate app , and IE is not allowing fonts to be downloaded on clients machine. its their security policy .. so have to go with the PNGs

Comment: @TylerH You are absolutely correct , thats what i am saying ...

i just put the css reference in the HTML and this below line... 

<div class="icon icon-ic_add_alert_white_24dp"></div>

IT should work like this as per API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```css
.icon {
  background-image: url(../images/sprite-alert-white.PNG);
}
.iconBlack {
  background-image: url(../images/sprite-alert-black.PNG);
}
```

```html
<div class="iconBlack icon-ic_add_alert_black_24dp"></div>
```

Comment: this works perfectly, but i cant change the CSS as its included in Bower Package provided by google, and there are more than 20 css files each defining atleast 10 times  ".icon{ ...} " classes...